# Validate a search expression with quotes and *

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression to validate some user entered text. I'd like to use the regular expression with an [ngPattern](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern) directive so should avoid using the `g` flag.

Essentially, there are a number of "simple" rules.

1. There must be one or more words.
2. Single quotes (`'`) are not allowed.
3. Double quotes (`"`) are allowed but must be paired, i.e. open and closing.
4. Paired double quotes must wrap one or more words.
5. No white space is allowed between a double quote and the word it adjacently wraps.
6. An asterisk (`*`) is not allowed unless it immediately precedes a closing double quote and follows a word, without whitespace.

Here are some examples.

```
example                        match

''                             false
'  '                           false
'  foo'                        true
'foo'                          true
'foo bar'                      true
'foo bar*'                     false
'"foo'                         false
'"foo"'                        true
'" foo"'                       false
'"foo "'                       false
'"foo bar"'                    true
'"foo *"'                      false
'"foo*"'                       true
'foo*"'                        false
'"foo*" "bar*"'                true
'foo "bar*"'                   true
'"foo* bar"'                   false
'"foo*" bar'                   true
```

I've created [unit tests here](https://regex101.com/r/kP2cQ7/3)

I'm struggling to get anywhere close,

I've got an expression like this

```
/(")(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1/
```

that will match text between paired double quotes. Something like this,

```
/^.*\*"$/
```

will match text that ends with `'*"'`,

as you can see, I've got a long way to go, please help.

Is it possible that a regular expression is the wrong way to do this?

Comment: Aren't 5 and 6 the same thing.

Comment: [Here, use this to help](https://regex101.com/r/oO9tO3/1)

Comment: @ndn, almost I think, but I don't want `*` to be a word on its own.

Comment: Getting there! [15/18 tests passing](https://regex101.com/r/oO9tO3/4)

Comment: @Martin, so close, I'd assign a bounty already.

Comment: @Jodrell, done + explanation. That was a fun waste of time. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
^(?=.*\b)(?=[^"]*("[^"]*"[^"]*)*$)(?![^"]*("[^"]*"[^"]*)*" *")(?!.*\*[^"])(?!.*[ "]\*)(?![^"]*("[^"]*"[^"]*)*[^"]*\*")(?![^"]*("[^"]*"[^"]*)*" \w)(?![^"]*("[^"]*"[^"]*)*"[^"]*\w ")'[^']*'$
```

[See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/kP2cQ7/6)

**Good luck using this in your production codebase**

Ok, so dafuq...

---

An important idea that we are going to reuse is how to reach a position, before which you know there were an even number of `"`s. Namely:

```
[^"]*("[^"]*"[^"]*)*
```

Unfortunately, we can't reuse patterns in javascript regexes, so we will have to repeat it where ever we need it. Namely:

---

> Double quotes (`"`) are allowed but must be paired, i.e. open and closing.

```
^(?=__even_quotes_pattern__$)
```

Basically, we say that from the start (`^`), when we iterate til the end (`$`) we match the said pattern, aka even number of `"`.

---

> No white space is allowed between a double quote and the word it adjacently wraps.

We will split this in two parts - doesn't happen on the left, doesn't happen on the right:

```
^(?!__even_quotes_pattern__" \w)
^(?!__even_quotes_pattern__\w ")
```

---

> Paired double quotes must wrap one or more words.

```
^(?!__even_quotes_pattern__" *")
```

(there are no paired quotes that wrap only spaces)

---

The rest of them are easier:

> There must be one or more words.

```
^(?=.*\b)
```

(at some point there is a word boundary (`\b`))

---

> Single quotes (') are not allowed.

(or from the interpretation in the comments, not allowed except for the ones that wrap the string)

```
^'[^']*'$
```

---

> An asterisk (*) is not allowed unless it immediately precedes a closing double quote and follows a word, without whitespace.

We will split this into three parts:

(1) Must precede a `"`:

```
(?!.*\*[^"])
```

(2) Must follow a non-`"` or space

```
(?!.*[ "]\*)
```

(3) It doesn't precede non-closing `"`:

```
(?!__even_quotes_pattern__[^"]*\*")
```

Comment: This doesn't meet the half of the examples he gives

Comment: @Martin, really? Which one?

Comment: [Go here](https://regex101.com/r/kP2cQ7/1), on the left, go to **unit tests**, and hit **►**. It passes 9/18

Comment: @Martin, you have included the single quotes in the tests.

Comment: I can confirm @Martin's analysis, but its a lot better than what I started with.

Comment: @Jodrell Should I be excluding single quotes?

Comment: @Martin, if they shouldn't be included, I can just wrap it in `''` and it will work.

Comment: @Martin, Ideally but as I didn't include a example for that I'd accept an answer without.

Comment: Hm, there are still some failures, hold on a sec.

Comment: @Martin, you haven't put the closing `'` on the last test and that made me wonder for 10 minutes. xd How do I edit the unit tests?

Comment: Lol I copied them directly from the original post - but you can't edit. Only remove and replace

Answer (score -1):

clean and simple function:

```
function myParser(string) {

    var string = string.trim(),
        wordsArray = string.split(' '),
        regExp = /((?=")^["][a-zA-Z]+[*]{0,1}["]$|^[a-zA-Z]+$)/,
        len = wordsArray.length,
        i = 0;

    // '"foo bar"' situation
    if (string.match(/^["][a-zA-Z]+[\s]?[a-zA-Z]+[*]{0,1}["]$/)) {
        return true;    
    }

    for (i; i < len; i++) {
        var result = wordsArray[i].match(regExp);
        if (result === null) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cy9ozmdm/ to check results.

If you need explanations - write in comment, I will write logic detailed.

(Idea for you: check 2 variants (clear regExp and function) - on 10.000 test situation - what works faster (and doesn't fail :))?)

Comment: While I would tend to agree that this is probably more easily done with a function and regex combo - the question *specifically* needs a regex solution